# When I try to start app for Mac instead IOS I got "Ambiguous use of 'object(forKey:)'"

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I have the following JSON:
{

```
payload =     {
    asks =         (
                    {
            price = "6.38";
            quantity = 100;
        }
    );
    bids =         (
                    {
            price = "6.37";
            quantity = 118;
        }
    );
    depth = 1;
};
```

And I have the following code:

```
      let payload = parsedJSON.object(forKey: "payload") as AnyObject
      let bids = payload.object(forKey: "bids") as AnyObject
      if bids.count > 0 {
            let bprice = (bids[0] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "price") as! Double
            let asks = payload.object(forKey: "asks") as AnyObject
            let aprice = (asks[0] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "price") as! Double
      }
```

Xcode is 12.5. Swift is 5.
For IOS everything is working.
As soon as I try to build app for My Mac I got the following error:
Ambiguous use of 'object(forKey:)'

[image]

What is wrong? Why for IOS it is working but for Mac it doesn't work?
How to fix this?
I read a lot of advices with "to change type to [String:Any]" but it doesn't work.

Comment: I would strongly suggest using Codable for this rather than doing the decoding by hand.

Comment: Are you using some 3rd party library that you forgot to include in the macOS target?

Comment: No. This code is working for IOS but doesn't work for Mac.  It is quite strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - assuming `parsedJSON is [String: Any]`

```
if let payload = parsedJSON["payload"] as? [String: Any],
   let bids = payload["bids"] as? [[String: Any]],
   let asks = payload["asks"] as? [[String: Any]],
   let bid = bids.first,
   let ask = asks.first {
      let bprice = bid["price"] as? Double ?? 0
      let aprice = ask["price"] as? Double ?? 0
}
```

Comment: How can you assume parsedJSON is a dictionary, to me it looks more like a custom type?

Comment: Not sure without seeing more code from OP, That's why I mentioned about this assumption.

Comment: Then why post an answer instead of asking for more information?

Comment: I will delete this post then. Thanks @JoakimDanielson

Comment: I checked. This code before doesn't work. Looks like I haven't got any useful ideas yet.

Comment: @DmitrySenashenko It doesn't work at all or some part of it is failing, I made this answer visible after seeing your answer about using a similar method.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody gave me good and advice and cleared it:

```
if let payload = parsedJSON["payload"] as? [String: Any],
let bids = payload["bids"] as? [[String: Any]],
let asks = payload["asks"] as? [[String: Any]],
let bid = bids.first,
let ask = asks.first {
    let bprice = bid["price"] as? Double ?? 0
    let aprice = ask["price"] as? Double ?? 0
}
```

And looks like it is working.
But I am quite confused how to work with arrays here.
I can use asks.first like asks[0] and asks.last like asks[asks.count-1] but for asks[1] Xcode gives error.
How to code this correctly?
[image]

Comment: The error is clear: Getting a value from an array with index subscripting returns a non-optional (or the code crashes). Replace the `,` with the `{`. And be aware that the value for `price` is a string, you will get always `0`.

Comment: See the answer I provided yesterday, I had to delete that according to the comments listed under that answer. For your current issue, the `if let` syntax works for optional types in Swift. `asks.first` returns an optional value, if the array is empty, it will return `nil` otherwise ask[0] will be returned. `asks[0]` doesn't return an optional value, it either gives a value, or if the array is empty it crashes your app. The solution is to write this `accounts[1]` inside `if`'s body not in the `if let` part.